# OpenCV unable to capture image from isight webcam

Tags: c++, opencv

I can not capture image from my webcam using following OpenCV code.

The code can show images from a local AVI file or a video device. It works fine on a "test.avi" file.

When I make use my default webcam(CvCapture* capture =cvCreateCameraCapture(0)), the program can detected the size of the image from webcam,but just **unable to display the image**.

/*I forgot to mention that I can see the iSight is working because the LED indicator is turn on*/

Anyone encounter the same problem?

```
cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

CvCapture* capture =cvCreateFileCapture( "C:\\test.avi" ) ;// display images from avi file, works well 
// CvCapture* capture =cvCreateCameraCapture(0); //display the frame(images) from default webcam not work 

assert( capture );
IplImage* image;

while(1) {
 image = cvQueryFrame( capture );
   if( !image ) break;

  cvShowImage( "Example2", image );

  char c = cvWaitKey(33);
  if( c == 27 ) break;
}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
```

- opencv 2.2
- Debug library *d.lib
- WebCam isight
- Macbook OS win7 32
- VS2008

Comment: I have the exact same problem and nearly the same setup (win7 64).  I've tried building opencv with and without qt support but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest update! Problem solved!

This happen to be one of OpenCV 2.2′s bug

Here is how to fix it:

http://dusijun.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/opencv-unable-to-capture-image-from-isight-webcam/

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on opencv 2.3 with Macbook pro Mid 2012 and I had that problem with the Isight cam. Somehow I managed to make it work on opencv by simply adjusting the parameters of the Cvcapture and adjusting the frame width and height:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 500 );
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600 );
```

You can also change these numbers to the frame width and height you want.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the example from the [opencv page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture)?

namely,

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Works on a macbook pro for me (although on OS X). If it doesn't work, some kind of error message would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The problem is yet not solved. When I check the "frame", the rows and clos are correct (480*640).I am not sure what should this "frame" looks like. I have a screenshot for this frame you can find it here http://dusijun.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/opencv-unable-to-capture-image-from-isight-webcam/ image 3

Comment: Does the webcam work with other programs? Might be just a driver issue.

Comment: Latest update! Problem solved!

This happen to be one of OpenCV 2.2′s bug

Here is how to fix it:

http://dusijun.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/opencv-unable-to-capture-image-from-isight-webcam/[^]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main(int, char**) {
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {  // check if we succeeded
        cout << "===couldn't open camera" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Mat edges, frame;
    frame = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8U);
    namedWindow("edges", 1);
    for (;;) {
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cout << "frame size: " << frame.cols << endl;
        if (frame.cols > 0 && frame.rows > 0) {
            imshow("edges", frame);
        }
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try

```
capture=cvCaptureFromCam(0);
```

I think this may work.

Let me know about wheather its working or not.

Comment: I feel that it's a bug or driver's problem